# How to get user JWT token in JWTStrategy (NestJS)?

Tags: jwt, nestjs

My problem is that I want to check if the login token is invalidated in the database (after changing password). However, the validate function in JWTStrategy only has access to the payload of the JWT, not the token. I would like to know if there is a way I can get the JWT token from the request in this class or JWTAuthGuard. Thanks!

```ts
  async validate(payload: LoginPayload) {
    const { email, firstName, lastName, sub } = payload;
    return {
      id: sub,
      email,
      firstName,
      lastName,
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

To get access to the token specifically, you need to pass `passReqToCallback: true` in the `super` call of the `JwtStrategy`'s `constructor`. Now the first parameter of the `JwtStrategy#validate` method is `req` and the second if the token payload, so you can call `req.headers['authorization'].split(' ')[1] to get the token itself. Something like:

```js
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: jwtConstants.secret,
      passReqToCallback: true
    });
  }

  async validate(req: e.Request, payload: LoginPayload) {
    const rawToken = req.headers['authorization'].split(' ')[1];
    const { email, firstName, lastName, sub } = payload;
    return {
      id: sub,
      email,
      firstName,
      lastName,
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this one is exactly what I look for!

Comment: Thanks Jay, this works gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

I enjoy it because `passReqToCallback` works fine.